# Plot separately different parts of a dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-analysis

I would like to plot from the seaborn dataset 'tips'.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
x1 = tips.loc[(df['time']=='lunch'), 'tip']
x2 = tips.loc[(df['time']=='dinner'),'tip']

x1.plot.kde(color='orange')
x2.plot.kde(color='blue')
plt.show()
```

I don't know exactly where it's wrong...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn's [`sns.kdeplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) supports the `hue` argument to split the plot between different categories:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.kdeplot(data=tips, x='tip', hue='time')
```

[image: KDE-plot]

Of course your approach could work too, but there are several problems with your code:

- What is `df`? Shouldn't that be `tips`?
- The category names `Lunch` and `Dinner` must be capitalized, as in the data.
- You're mixing different indexing techniques. It should be e.g. `x1 = tips.tip[tips['time'] == 'Lunch']`.
- If you want to plot two KDE in the same diagram, they should be scaled according to sample size. With my approach above, seaborn has done that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As you are loading data from the seaborn built-in datasets check that your column names are case sensitive replace them with correct name. 
You can plot the cumulative distribution between the time and density as follows:

```
sns.kdeplot(
data=tips, x="total_bill", hue="time",
cumulative=True, common_norm=False, common_grid=True,
)
```